# How to export default Object.freeze in dynamic import?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, import, module, export

I'm trying to export a frozen object within a dynamically imported module, and it's failing.

My main module is:

```
import ('./hello.mjs').then(function (o) {
    o.hello();
});
```

My imported module, hello.mjs, has this code:

```
function hello () {
    console.log('Hello');
}

export default Object.freeze({ hello });
```

The program fails with this error in the console:

> `TypeError: o.hello is not a function at main.mjs:2`

However, if I use a simple export, like this:

```
function hello () {
    console.log('Hello');
}

export { hello };
```

...then it works. Exporting default frozen objects works with non-dynamic module imports. Why do dynamic module imports behave differently, and what can I do to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fulfillment value of the promise from dynamic import is the [*module namespace object*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-module-namespace-objects) for the module. (See [FinishDynamicImport](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-finishdynamicimport) in the spec.) To access the default export, use the property `default` on it, perhaps via destructuring:

```
import ('./hello.mjs').then(function ({default: o}) {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^
    o.hello();
});
```

Comment: FWIW, my new book is out in a couple of months. I go into modules, including dynamic import, in a fair bit of detail in Chapter 13. See my profile for links, etc.